# <C-w>= doesn't work

Tags: neovim, window-management

When I press `<C-w>`, whichkey tells me that pressing `=` leads to "equally high and wide".

However this only works for horizontal splits but not for vertical ones.

How can I have "equally high and way" if for example I have two horizontal splits on the left and one vertical splits on the right?

Comment: It should work for all the "Normal" (i.e.: the splits that don't have `winfixheight` or `winfixwidth`) splits (in particular not for the QuickFix list of the Location list and other special windows) unless `<C-w>=` has been remapped. What is the result of `:wincmd =`? What is the result of `:verbose map <C-w>=`?

Comment: I have two text buffers on the left side in horizontal splits and a terminal on the right size in a vertical split

Comment: `:wincmd =` returns nothing. The second command shows: `n  <C-W>       * <Cmd>lua require("which-key").show("\23", {mode = "n", auto = true})<CR>
        Last set from Lua`

Comment: Did `:wincmd =` resize your splits? what is the result of `:set winfixheight?` and `:set winfixwidth?` on the splits that do not resize? What if on these splits you do `:set nowinfixheight` and `:set nowinfixwidth`?

Comment: `:wincmd =` does nothing. `:set winfixheight?` returns `winfixheight` and  `:set winfixwidth?` returns `winfixwidth`. Calling `:set nowinfixheight` and `:set nowinfixwidth` on the window that did not resize worked. Is a terminal supposed to come with those variables set? Or is it `iron.nvim` and sets them for me?

Comment: I suppose `iron.nvim` set it for you ;-)

Comment: Indeed: https://github.com/Vigemus/iron.nvim/issues/287

Comment: Do you have still something open in your question? How can we help you further? Otherwise maybe could you accept one of the solution using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)

Comment: @Vivian De Smedt ok thanks

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :-) Open question keep popping up when they are not accepted. It creates some confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl w</kbd>`=` resizes all the windows (aka splits) that don't have the following options `winfixheight` and/or `winfixwidth` set.

The following script should resize all the window to "equal" height and width (whatever it means):

```
windo set nowinfixheight
windo set nowinfixwidth
wincmd =
```

More information with [:help CTRL-W_=](https://vimhelp.org/windows.txt.html#CTRL-W_%3D)